# Average number of distinct values

Tags: probability, statistics, finite-groups

Let $q$ such that $q < n$. I pick at random $n$ values in $\mathbb{F}_q$.

What is the average number of distinct values ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Imagine that the picking is done one at a time, with replacement. Define random variable $X_i$ by $X_i=1$ if the object chosen at stage $i$ is different from all the objects chosen at stages $\lt i$. Let $X_i=0$ otherwise.

Then the number of distinct objects is $\sum_1^n X_i$.
So our mean is $\sum E(X_i)$.

For $E(X_i)$, the probability that $X_i=1$, this does not depend on the object picked at stage $i$. Let it be $1$. We want the probability that none of the objects chosen in stages $1$ to $i-1$ is equal to $1$. The probability of this is $\left(1-\frac{1}{q}\right)^{i-1}$. Now add up the geometric series, $i=1$ to $n$.

Comment: Thank you very much André.

Comment: You are welcome. Did's answer is (of course) better, since in effect he used random variables $Y_1,Y_2,\dots, Y_q$ which tell us whether object $i$ was picked. I used random variables that look at the picks. For his choice, the $\Pr(Y_i=1)$ are easy, and all equal. My $\Pr(X_i=1)$ are not all equal, so summation (luckily easy) is needed.

Comment: I have a question André. You write "For $E(X_i)$, the probability that $X=i$". Is there a typing error ? $X$ is not defined.

Comment: Thank you, typo. It was meant to be $\Pr(X_i=1)$. For a Bernoulli random variable $W$ (values only $1$ or $0$) we have $E(W)=\Pr(W=1)$. That (and linearity of expectation) is what makes the method of indicator random variables so powerful,

Comment: OK. Thanks again André

Answer (score 1):

Each value in $\mathbb F_q$ is *not drawn* with probability $(1-q^{-1})^n$ hence the average number of distinct values in a sample of size $n$ is $q\cdot(1-(1-q^{-1})^n)$.

For example, when $q\to\infty$, the average number of distinct values in a sample of size $c\cdot q$ is approximately $(1-\mathrm e^{-c})\cdot q$.

Comment: Thanks Did. In fact $q$ is lower than $n$. I update my question.